# Create a new column based on several lookup tables in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe (`df_orig`) and several lookup tables (also dataframes) that correspond to each of the segments in `df_orig`.

Here's a small subset of `df_orig`:

```
segment score1 score2 
 B3         0   700
 B1         0   120
 B1       400   950
 B1       100   220
 B1       200   320
 B1       650   340
 B5       300   400
 B5         0   320
 B1         0   240
 B1       100   360
 B1       940   700
 B3       100   340
```

And here's a lookup table in its entirety for segment B5 called `thresholds_b5` (there is a lookup table for each segment in the large dataset):

```
score1 score2   
990     220
980     280
970     200
960     260
950     260
940     200
930     240
920     220
910     220
900     220
850     120
800     220
750     220
700     120
650     200
600     220
550     220
500     240
400     240
300     260
200     300
100     320
  0     400
```

I want to create a new column in my large dataset that is analagous to this SQL logic:

```SQL
case when segment = 'B5' then
   case when score1 = 990 and score2 >= 220 then 1
   case when score1 = 980 and score2 >= 280 then 1
   .
   .
   .
   else 0
case when segment = 'B1' then
.
.
.
else 0 end as indicator
```

I was able to get the correct output using a loop based on the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497396/how-do-i-create-a-new-column-based-on-conditions-of-other-columns-in-pandas):

```
df_b5 = df_orig[df_orig.loc[:,'segment'] == 'B5']

for i,row in enumerate(thresholds_b5):

    value1 = thresholds_b5.iloc[i,0]
    value2 = thresholds_b5.iloc[i,1]

    df_b5.loc[(df_b5['score1'] == value1) & (df_b5['score2'] >= value2), 'indicator'] = 1
```

However, I'd need another loop to run this for each segment and then append all of the resultant dataframes back together, which is a bit messy. Furthermore, while I only have three segments (B1,B3,B5) for now, I'm going to have 20+ segments in the future.

Is there a way to do this more succinctly and preferably without loops? I've been warned that loops over dataframes tend to be slow and given the size of my dataset I think speed will matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ok with sorting the DataFrames ahead of time, then you can replace your loop example with the new [asof join in pandas 0.19](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0190-enhancements-asof-merge):

```
# query
df_b5 = df_orig.query('segment == "B5"')

# sort ahead of time
df_b5.sort_values('score2', inplace=True)
threshold_b5.sort_values('score2', inplace=True)

# set the default indicator as 1
threshold_b5['indicator'] = 1

# join the tables
df = pd.merge_asof(df_b5, threshold_b5, on='score2', by='score1')

# fill missing indicators as 0
df.indicator = np.int64(df.indicator.fillna(0.0))
```

This is what I got:

```
  segment  score1  score2  indicator
0      B5       0     320          0
1      B5     300     400          1
```

If you need the original order, then save the index in a new column of `df_orig` and then resort the final DataFrame by that.

---

[pandas 0.19.2 added multiple `by` parameters](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/whatsnew.html#enhancements), so you could `concat` all of your thresholds with the `segment` column set for each one, then invoke:

```
pd.merge_asof(df_orig, thresholds, on='score2', by=['segment', 'score1'])
```

Comment: Wow! It's really a very useful new feature!

Comment: Thanks for this! Just to make sure I'm understanding, I'll still need a loop to run the code for each segment in `df_orig['segment'].unique()` given the multiple by parameters limitation, right?

Comment: @D.Ross That is correct. Your outer loop over the unique segments will stay the same, for now.

Comment: @chrisaycock awesome. I'll accept your answer once I get my pandas upgraded to 0.19.0 tonight off my corporate network.